# String Format property in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, string, format

I work in ASP.NET c# and MySQL database.

I keep getting an error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

My code:

```
string sql = String.Format(@" UPDATE `doTable` ");
sql += String.Format(" SET Active = {0} ");
sql += String.Format(" WHERE ID = {1}; ", Active.ToString(), ID.ToString());
```

If try this instead the code working, what is the difference? :

```
string sql = String.Format(@"UPDATE `doTable` SET 
                                     Active = {0}
                                     WHERE ID = {1}; ",
                                     Active.ToString(),
                                     ID.ToString());
```

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Comment: it's because you are using `string.format` without any parameters when building the sql string

Comment: try: this instead: `sql += String.Format(" SET Active = {0} ", Active.ToString());` etc for both strings

Comment: Don't home brew parametrized statements, use a `MySqlCommand` which does this for you.

Comment: and as Alex says -`naughty, naughty` to build sql injection prone strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use String.Format for building queries. This is open to sql injection, you should use `SqlCommand.Parameters`. Also you could have numerous problems with ToString() with DataTime types and Decimal depending of cultures.

```
string sql = @"UPDATE [doTable] 
                  SET Active = @Active
                WHERE ID = @ID";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql)) {
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", Active);
```

Comment: `SqlCommand`? And [`AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)? Sorry but I don't quite understand why OP select this as an answer. (_No offense_)

Answer (score 3):

The problem on that line;

```
sql += String.Format(" SET Active = {0} ");
```

You declared an index component for `String.Format` but you never add it's format string component. But in your second example, you did. Every statement works as a separate one. That's why this line throws exception but your second code part not.

From [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation;

> A
>   `FormatException` is thrown at runtime if a parameter specifier
>   designates an item outside the bounds of the list of objects.

#### But do not use this way!

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE `doTable` SET  Active = @active WHERE ID = @id";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Active.ToString();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.ToString();
     // I assumed your columns are VarChar type.

     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I *strongly* suspect your `ID` should be a numeric type instead of character based on it's name by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to build yor queries this way, you should modify your code to be like this:

```
string sql = String.Format(@" UPDATE `doTable` ");
sql += String.Format(" SET Active = {0} ", Active.ToString());
sql += String.Format(" WHERE ID = {0}; ",  ID.ToString());
```

But it is bad aproach. Consider to use **SqlCommand Parameters**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are defining 2 arguments in two different strings.
Change it to this:

```
string sql = String.Format(@" UPDATE `doTable` ");
sql += String.Format(" SET Active = {0} ", Active.ToString());
sql += String.Format(" WHERE ID = {0}; ", ID.ToString());
```

Comment: It should be `" WHERE ID = {0}; "` (please, note `0`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You're right! I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should always provide as many arguments as the largest placeholder value + 1.

The second line in your code contains the placeholder `{0}`, but does not provide a value as an argument, so the software cannot complete the string.

In the second example, you provide two placeholders `{0}` and `{1}` and two arguments (`Active.ToString()` and `ID.ToString()`), so both placeholders can be replaced by an argument.

You can also provide more arguments than placeholders (like in the third line of your code), but this rarely makes sense, since extra values will not be used.